# Can AWS EventBridge directly to call HTTP API on ECS container that is running a java application?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I'm developing an event driven architecture (study phase).
The idea is to have an API Gateway that will receive externals calls to microservices that will runs on ECS (the microservices are made in java/spring).
To decouple the microservice the goal is to use the Eventbridge to receive event from publish microservices and sent the event to consumer microservices. The questions is: Can Eventbridge to send event to a microservice on ecs calling the http endpoint of the consumer?

The microservices are on the same account as EventBridge, so I guess that API Destinations would not be a good solution.

I read the documentation and didn't find informations about it. I saw some project where there is an SQS that receive the event and the consumer needs to pull every time for updates (I don't like of this approach).

What would be the best way to solve this problem? What is the state of art for this scenario?

---

UPDATE

The answer is YES! It's possible to use the Eventbridge to call an endpoint in a app into a container (ecs/fargate).
You just have to add the service as target and config.
[image: Eventbridge target configuration]

Choose the Eventbridge API Destination, create a new API destination, place the URL and add a authentication connection (only if necessary).

Comment: "The microservices are on the same account as EventBridge, so I guess that API Destinations would not be a good solution." Why would that not be a good solution? That is literally the exact solution for the project you have described.

Comment: Thank you for you comment @MarkB 
All examples I saw always used API Destinations for external communications, and because of that, I thought that was not a good approach.

Comment: If you keep the endpoints private, you will have to do something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sending-amazon-eventbridge-events-to-private-endpoints-in-a-vpc/

Comment: Using API Gateway for the internal calls would also work well.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I need to study more about security to decide if I'll to hide the endpoints. I already tested the solution with the API gateway, but I'm not sure because it will raise the costs.